# VBA Code to Delete Rows if Cell is Blank Not Working

Tags: excel, vba

I've put together the code below to delete rows where the cell in column E is empty. It isn't working. I think the reason is that although the cells appear to be empty when I use the formula `=IF(E2="","empty","not empty")` the result is that the cell is not empty.

Can anyone suggest how to change the macro to deal with this?

```
Sub DeleteRow()
    Dim r As Long
    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("List").Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row
    For r = LastRow To 1 Step -1
        If Cells(r, 1) = "" Then
            Rows(r).Delete
        End If
    Next r
End Sub
```

Comment: Try to figure out the content of the cell - if it is only blank(s), use `Trim`, but if there are other characters in it, you need to check for that

Comment: Why instead using a formula don't you check your condition inside the loop? change `If Cells(r, 1) = "" Then` for `If IsEmpty(Cells(r, "E")) Then` that way you will check inside the macro wether your column E is empty or not.

Comment: @FaneDuru I thought he had that formula in column A referencing to column E, if in column E he has also a formula, indeed my approach won't work. We need more details on the matter.

Comment: Try if Cells(r, 5) = "", Cells(r, 1)  has reference to column A.

Comment: Also, are you sure your code is looping through the right worksheet? Without qualifying that inside your loop as well as when you define the last row, it will simply work on the currently active sheet. Apart from that, I'd echo FunThomas's recommandation to try to figure out what the macro finds in `Cells(r,1)` (these cells will be in column A, btw, but I'd think you knew that already?)

Comment: When deleting rows where a cell in a column is empty, how will you figure out that there are not rows to be deleted after the last cell containing data? Usually you would then rather calculate the last row in another column (I like to call it¨LastRowColumn) e.g. you calculate the last row using column A, and then loop through column E to delete rows.

Comment: @VBasic2008 But rob is working from the bottom up here - is there something I am missing in your comment?

Comment: @eirikdaude: OP has calculated the last row using the column where the cells will be checked if they're empty. What if there is data in other columns below the calculated row? I would guess that he wants to delete those rows, too.

Comment: That's a big assumption @VBasic2008 Personally I feel there isn't enough information here to figure out why OP's code doesn't work but ymmv

Comment: Instead of `=IF(E2="","empty","not empty")` try `=CODE(E2)` to find out exactly which 'invisible' character is in the cell. The space character e.g., is 32. There can also be a non-breaking space, various flavors of new line etc.

Comment: Hi @rob,, check my post below,, I've fixed the issue ☺

Comment: Thanks VBasic2008. The formula returned 32 so it seems there is a space.

Answer (score 0):

### Delete Row If Cell Is Blank

- Here are three solution sorted by efficiency the last being the most efficient.
- Adjust the constants to fit your needs.

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub DeleteRow()
    
    ' Define constants.
    Const wsName As String = "List"
    Const FirstRow As Long = 1
    Const LastRowCol As Variant = 1 ' or "A"
    Const CriteriaCol As Variant = 5 ' or "E"
    Const Criteria As Variant = "" ' or Empty
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    
    ' Create a reference to the worksheet.
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Worksheets(wsName)
    ' Calculate last row.
    Dim LastRow As Long: LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, LastRowCol).End(xlUp).Row
    
    ' Loop cells and delete rows.
    Dim r As Long
    For r = LastRow To FirstRow Step -1
        If ws.Cells(r, CriteriaCol) = Criteria Then ws.Rows(r).Delete
    Next r

End Sub

Sub DeleteRowBetter()
    
    ' Define constants.
    Const wsName As String = "List"
    Const FirstRow As Long = 1
    Const LastRowCol As Variant = "A"
    Const CriteriaCol As Variant = 5 ' or "E"
    Const Criteria As Variant = ""
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    
    ' Create a reference to the worksheet.
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Worksheets(wsName)
    ' Calculate last row.
    Dim LastRow As Long: LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, LastRowCol).End(xlUp).Row
    
    ' Loop cells.
    Dim URng As Range, r As Long
    For r = FirstRow To LastRow
        If ws.Cells(r, CriteriaCol).Value = Criteria Then GoSub collectCells
    Next r

    ' Delete in one go.
    If Not URng Is Nothing Then URng.EntireRow.Delete

Exit Sub

collectCells:
    If Not URng Is Nothing Then
        Set URng = Union(URng, ws.Cells(r, 1))
    Else
        Set URng = ws.Cells(r, 1)
    End If
    Return
   
End Sub

Sub DeleteRowBest()
    
    ' Define constants.
    Const wsName As String = "List"
    Const FirstRow As Long = 1
    Const LastRowCol As Variant = 1 ' or "A"
    Const CriteriaCol As Variant = 5 ' or "E"
    Const Criteria As Variant = ""
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    
    ' Create a reference to the worksheet.
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Worksheets(wsName)
    ' Calculate last row.
    Dim LastRow As Long: LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, LastRowCol).End(xlUp).Row
    ' Create a reference to the column range.
    Dim rng As Range: Set rng = ws.Range(ws.Cells(FirstRow, CriteriaCol), _
                                         ws.Cells(LastRow, CriteriaCol))
    
    ' Loop cells.
    Dim cel As Range, URng As Range
    For Each cel In rng.Cells
        If cel.Value = Criteria Then GoSub collectCells
    Next cel

    ' Delete in one go.
    If Not URng Is Nothing Then URng.EntireRow.Delete

Exit Sub

collectCells:
    If Not URng Is Nothing Then
        Set URng = Union(URng, cel)
    Else
        Set URng = cel
    End If
    Return
   
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

*Try this simple code, deletes those row/rows has any cell is blank is column E.*

```
Sub DeleteROW()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Columns("E:E").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

**:Edited:**

*With little corrections your code also works.*

```
Sub DeleteRow()
    
    Dim r As Long
    Dim LastRow As Long
    
    LastRow = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("List").Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row
    
    For r = LastRow To 1 Step -1
        If IsEmpty(Cells(r, "E")) = True Then
            Rows(r).Delete
        End If
    Next r
    
End Sub
```

**N.B.**

This line needs few corrections,

**earlier it was,**

```
If Cells(r, 1) = "" Then
```

Here in `cells(r, 1)`, the `1` represents Column 1 and VBA does not supports it.

**Now is,**

```
If IsEmpty(Cells(r, "E")) = True Then
```

*IsEmpty is better than using `= ""`*

Comment: Please write your concern that why this has been down voted,, help me to improve,,!